# python : Sorting a list of dict basing on an element which is time string

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of dicts. Among other elements, each dict in the list has a date and time element which looks like - `2018-08-14T14:42:14`. I have written a function which compares two such strings and returns the most recent one. How do I use this to sort the list (most recent first)? Also, each dict is quite big in size hence, if possible, I would like to get the indices of array sorted (according to the time element) rather than the whole array. I have seen other similar questions on this site but all of them tell about sorting basing on a known data type like int or string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dates written in ISO format have one nice property - if you sort them alphabetically, you sort them according to date values also (if the belong to one timezone, of course). Just use [list.sort()](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.list.sort) function to do that. That will sort list in-place. Anyway you should not worry about memory, since creating the second sorted list will not take much memory since it holds references to dictionaries in the first list.

```
a = [
    {'time': '2018-01-02T00:00:00Z'},
    {'time': '2018-01-01T00:00:00Z'},
]

a.sort(key=lambda x: x['time'])
print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! But just out of curiosity, if the time string was not comparable without some user defined function, how can we sort it?

Answer (score 2):

We sort on the time by converting it to a python datetime object, which has natural ordering like int. So, you need not worry about the format of the time string.

```
# l is the list of the dicts, each dict contains a key "time". 
l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x["time"], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
```